# How to retrieve list of parseusers in push notification using Parse in Android App

Tags: android, json, list, arraylist, parse-platform

[image]We are new to push notification concept,we have installed our App into three mobiles & names are registered in parse server names like tab,sam,sony.
Now we need to get three names in one list.
we tried but we don't have luck!

```
JSONObject i1=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getJSONObject("user");//user is key in parse
             System.out.println("users "+i1);
```

another way

```
 ParseObject pa1=(ParseObject) ParseObject.fetchAll("user");
```

we need all user registred in parse.Because we need to send push notification individually based on name fromUI.

Please tell me if it is possible or not.
if possible guide me.....!

Comment: Dear user1838846, I do not understand your question. Let me clarify. You want to send push notification to users where you list these users in UI. Am I right? So you need to list of users in Parse?

Comment: @kingspeech,just we need to retrieve users from parse to our app

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand your question. So, you want to query the Parse Installation table and retrieve the user column values. You can achieve this via writing a cloud function where you have to user Parse.Installation query. For example below code query the Installation table and retrieve all of user column values;

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("getUsers", function(request, response) 
{

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  var usernameList = "";
  query.find({
  success: function(results){
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
     { 
        usernameList += results[i].get('user')+"~";
     }
     response.success(usernameList);
    },
    error: function(error) {
     //error
     console.log("error: " + error);
     response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

You can write this cloud function to your Parse cloud and you can trigger this function from your android application. The above code will produce the users name with ~ separated. You can look the Parse tutorials to dig into Cloud function and how to trigger cloud function from your android application. Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: @kingsspeech thanks for guiding.But Parse Cloud is not supporting in eclipse IDE

Comment: Dear user1838846; Parse Cloud is not a kind of thing that can be supported by Eclipse. You can create a cloud Repository on your local machine and write the javascript code and deploy to Parse Cloud server. Please check the link; https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Comment: Dear user1838846; if the answer solves your problem then please accept it so other can benefit from it. Regards.