# How to get all registered users from parse

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications

We are developing an Android app. In the app we are using `parse_server` for `push-notification` [We followed this](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/Android). We save data like user_Name and user_Age in parse server. Now we need to get all `User_Name`. But we have only Get current mobile `user_Name.Code` like this

```
JSONObject i1=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getJSONObject("user");//user is key in parse
             System.out.println("users "+i1);    \
```

Please guide me how to get registered users from parse. Above like use get current mobile user name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query the Parse Installation table in order to find registered user to send Push notification. You can write a cloud function where you can trigger from your application. This question has already asked and please check the answer.
[How to retrieve list of parseusers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788748/how-to-retrieve-list-of-parseusers-in-push-notification-using-parse-in-android-a/29794634?noredirect=1#comment47718992_29794634) Hope this helps.

Regards.